# How to draw rectangles in the plot of a networkx graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a graph which I want to plot and then add some customization to it. In particular, I want to draw boxes around some groups of nodes and I want to write text.

So far I could not make it work. I read that the right way to do it would be to use the add_patches method.

Here is my non-working code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
    import networkx as nx
    from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

    f = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))

    G=nx.Graph()
    ndxs = [1,2,3,4]
    G.add_nodes_from(ndxs)
    G.add_weighted_edges_from( [(1,2,0), (1,3,1) , (1,4,-1) , (2,4,1) , (2,3,-1), (3,4,10) ] ) 
    nx.draw(G, nx.spring_layout(G, random_state=100))

    plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle((50,100),40,30,linewidth=1,edgecolor='b',facecolor='none'))
```

My problem is, the last line does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinates are way outside the window.
If you run `plt.xlim()` (or `plt.ylim()`) you'll see that the extent of the axes is close to [-1,1] whereas you're trying to day a Rectangle at coordinates [50,100].

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,5))

G=nx.Graph()
ndxs = [1,2,3,4]
G.add_nodes_from(ndxs)
G.add_weighted_edges_from( [(1,2,0), (1,3,1) , (1,4,-1) , (2,4,1) , (2,3,-1), (3,4,10) ] ) 
nx.draw(G)

ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0,0),0.1,0.1,linewidth=1,edgecolor='b',facecolor='none'))
```

[image]

I'm not familiar with how networkx works, so I don't know if there's a way to correctly calculate the coordinates of the rectangle you need. One approach would be to draw the rectangle in *axes coordinates* (the top left of the axes is 0,0 and bottom-right is 1,1), instead of data coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,5))

G=nx.Graph()
ndxs = [1,2,3,4]
G.add_nodes_from(ndxs)
G.add_weighted_edges_from( [(1,2,0), (1,3,1) , (1,4,-1) , (2,4,1) , (2,3,-1), (3,4,10) ] ) 
nx.draw(G)

ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0.25,0.25),0.5,0.5,linewidth=1,edgecolor='b',facecolor='none', transform=ax.transAxes))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works. I have to add, what really helped me was not to change the position of the rectangle, but to change the first line to "f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,5))". Only changing the position is not enough.